# visIgraphLayout causing display issues for shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, visnetwork

I can share the code if needed but it felt like a lot to share to start, so I'll try to explain narratively. I am creating an interface to display network data (as you might have guessed from the title). My first issue has been going on for a few days where *visIgraphLayout* is not laying out my visual correctly. Regardless of using "full" or "square" as the "type", the network map extends beyond the edge of the display space. When I resize the interface window, then the map will snap to full. Why won't it simply resize automatically? If it matters, I do have the output space in a box element. Also, I have the layout styles working off radiobuttons, and when I switch between styles the map goes beyond the edges again.

Part 2 begins. While the above problem is annoying, it was livable. However, a new wrinkle popped up. I added some font size control to my *visNodes* code - i.e., radiobuttons set to switch between *off* (0), *small* (5), *standard* (14), and *large* (40) font size options. Once I implemented this code, when I resize the interface window, now the network map disappears completely after initial load. If I select a new label option, it will redraw but beyond the edges of the space.

All the issues resolve themselves if I ditch the *visIgraphLayout*, but then I lose the layout functionality which I really like.

I hope this is clear enough. I really appreciate any insights the community might provide. Be well.

Comment: Myself and others may be able to help. There are an a fantastical number of ways in which you could be implementing the code and there are just as many possibilities as to what is going wrong (or not quite right). It looks like you're new to SO; welcome to the community! If you want great answers quickly, it's best to make your question reproducible. This includes sample data like the output from `dput()` or `reprex::reprex()` and any libraries you are using. Check it out: [making R reproducible questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269). You can also look at the `Shiny` example that come

Answer (score 0):

I think I have figured out an answer. Long story short, certain pieces didn't work and play well with others. Went through and build it again, and all it good.

Cheers.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).